# How do I set a default value for a ASPX UserControl property?

Tags: c#, user-controls, default-value, custom-properties

I have a user control defined on an page as follows:

```
<uc:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl" runat="server" Visible="true" />
```

I am wanting to reuse the same control on a different page with a custom property as follows:

```
<uc:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl" runat="server" Visible="true" 
MyCustomProperty="MyCustomText" />
```

The purpose of MyCustomProperty is to control some text in MyUserControl to be whatever I specify it to be.

For the first case I want the text to be "View" and for the second case I want it to be "MyCustomText".

In my user control I have the following code to define the property:

```
[DefaultValue("View")]
public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
```

I also have the following code to update the text based on the property:

```
LinkButton buttonSelect = e.Item.FindControl("ButtonSelect") as LinkButton;
if(buttonSelect != null) buttonSelect.Text = MyCustomProperty;
```

What actually happens is that when the custom property isn't supplied in the first case then MyCustomProperty == null.

I've tried to specify that the default should be "View" by adding the DefaultValue attribute but it hasn't had the affect that I intended.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DefaultValueAttribute` is used by visual designers and code generators to identify the default value, so they can more intelligently generate code. In Visual Studio, this attribute will cause a property to be shown in bold when the property returns a value that differs from the value declared in the attribute.

`DefaultValueAttribute` does not actually set the default value of the property for you. To do this, simply specify a suitable default value in your constructor. In your case:

```
public partial class MyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        MyCustomProperty = "View";
    }

    ...
}
```

Also, be aware that the property as you have coded it will not survive Postbacks. If this is important behaviour between round trips, be sure to add it to view state!

Comment: In my case Postbacks are not an issue so your answer was just what I needed. I really should have looked up DefaultValue on MSDN but I was busy with so many other things that it didn't cross my mind...which is silly I know... thanks heaps for your help!

Answer (score 2):

How about setting the property value explicitly rather than using the DefaultValue attribute?

```
private string _MyCustomProperty = "View";
public string MyCustomProperty 
{
  get
  {
    return _MyCustomProperty;
  }
  set
  {
    _MyCustomProperty = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the note given in MSDN about [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx), you'll understand what you are doing wrong -

> A `DefaultValueAttribute` will not
>   cause a member to be automatically
>   initialized with the attribute's
>   value. You must set the initial value
>   in your code.